# Shooting a club is Baire

Tags: set-theory, forcing

I'm attempting this problem from Kunen:

[image]

I'm trying to do it by a direct combinatorial argument. Namely, let $C$ be the set of countable ordinals for which there exist such an $\omega$-chain. I want to see that $C$ is club. The fact that $C$ is unbounded is easy. I'm stuck on checking that it's closed. It's enough to consider the case $D_0\supset D_1\supset\dots$.

If $\gamma$ is a limit point of $C$, we can pick an increasing sequence $\langle\gamma_k:n<\omega\rangle$ which converges to $\gamma$, with each $\gamma_k\in C$. So we can choose $\langle p_n^k:k<\omega\rangle$ witnessing $\gamma_k\in C$. I tried to extract some sequence by a diagonal process, but the problem is that, in passing from $p_n^k$ to $p_m^{k+1}$, the later need not end-extend the former, which is part of the requirement. And we can't carelessly apply the density of the $D_n$ because we might add sets whose maximum is above $\gamma$.

Comment: This Q is also in Kunen's first book, minus the hint, and minus the last sentence of the exercise. (Instead, it  points out that if $S$ is co-stationary then $\omega_1$ \  $S$ is non-stationary in a generic extension.) ....I still haven't figured out a combinatoric proof that $\Bbb P_S$ is Baire....  I have been told that it can be done by showing that if $T$ is any countable closed subset of $\omega_1$ then $\{x\in  \omega_1: \exists y\in \omega_1\,(\,S\cap [x,y)$ is order-isomorphic to $T\,)\}$  is uncountable.

Comment: I am not sure if Kunen means anything special with "direct combinatorial argument", other than writing down what's happening in elementary submodel argument. Construct an increasing continuous sequence of countable sets $P_\alpha$ of conditions so that for each $\alpha$, $\beta < \alpha$ and each $p \in P_\alpha$ there is $p' \leq p$ in $P_{\alpha+1}$ so that $\max p' \geq \beta$. Now consider $\{\alpha \in \operatorname{Lim} : P_\alpha \subseteq \mathbb{P}_{S \cap \alpha} \}$.

Answer (score 1):

I suspect you are misinterpreting the hint, it says you need to produce a particular club with the required property, not that the club to consider is defined by that property.

In particular it might be beneficial to instead show that the set $X$ of all $\delta\in \omega_1$ that are limit points of $S$ and for which there is a countable $A\subset \mathbb{P}_S$ such that

1. $(A,\le)$ is atomless with $p \in A$,
2. For each $n\in \omega$, $A\cap D_n$ is relatively dense in $A$,
3. For every $q \in A$ and $\alpha \in \delta \cap S$, $q\cap \alpha \cup \{ \alpha \} \in A$, and
4. $\{\max(q): q\in A\} \subset \delta$.

contains a club.